# Pass multidimensional array from $http in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have an array in AngularJS and I want to pass through `$http` to treat in PHP (back-end), but am unable to. I am able to pass `$scope.myForm.shopList` without any issues, but when I send `$scope.myForm` the php does not receive any data.

Angular:

```
goSoft.controller('createShop', function($scope, $http){  
  $scope.myForm = [];
  $scope.myForm.shopList = [];

  $scope.shopListAdd = [{
    cod_prod : '',
    ref_prod : '',
    cant: '',
    fabricante : '',
    fecha_vence : '',
    vr_compra:'',
    vr_venta:'',
    iva:''
  }];

  $scope.add = function(shopAdd) {
    var index = $scope.shopListAdd.indexOf(shopAdd);
    $scope.shopListAdd.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.myForm.shopList.push(angular.copy(shopAdd))


    $scope.shopListAdd.push({
      cod_prod:'',
      ref_prod:'',
      cant: '',
      fabricante : '',
      fecha_vence : '',
      vr_compra:'',
      vr_venta:'',
      iva:''
    })
  }                

  $scope.submitForm = function(){    

    $http.post('../compras/objCompra.php?type=1', {datos:$scope.myForm}).success(
      function(data){
        console.log(data);
      })
  }})
```

PHP:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
         print_r($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the keys in $scope.myForm = {}

```
$scope.myForm = {};
  $scope.myForm.shopList = [];

  $scope.shopListAdd = [{
    cod_prod : '',
    ref_prod : '',
    cant: '',
    fabricante : '',
    fecha_vence : '',
    vr_compra:'',
    vr_venta:'',
    iva:''
  }];
```

php and I did this:

```
print_r($data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true));
```